# Is it possible to log all powershell commands run on a machine?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, powershell-3.0

We have some .net applications running on a server that run powershell scripts. Is there a setting where we can log every single powershell command run on that machine, without modifying our existing applications? I already tried `start-transcript` . That command only captures the commands run in the current session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Microsoft calls what you're after "Over the Shoulder Transcription".  It's described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/06/09/powershell-the-blue-team.aspx), and will be available in WMF5.

Comment: Transcript logging (+ script block logging and module logging) is available in [the latest preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48729), should OP want to test if this is the functionality he's after